# angular. How to import css from node_modules

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular-components

I'm using angular 5. Im my module I'm using leaflet 1.2.0.

In leaflet.css I have trouble with images, for example, some css lines:

```
.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/leaflet/layers-2x.png);
  background-size: 26px 26px;
}

/* Default icon URLs */
.leaflet-default-icon-path {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/leaflet/marker-icon.png);
}
```

So, I need to access leaflet.css to its relative route, what I tried:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  template:`<div id="myId" class="myClass"></div>`,
   styleUrls: ['./myComponent.component.scss','/../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'],
})
```

The folder structure:

```
--project_folder
  --node_modules
     --leaflet
         --dist
           --leaflet.css
  --src
    --app
      --myComponentParent
        --myComponent
          --myComponent.component.ts
          --myComponent.component.scss
          --myComponent.component.html
```

Can I refer to folder out of src? How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Angular CLI, you will need to add the Leaflet CSS file to the styles array contained in .`angular-cli.json` and remove css import from other places

```
"styles": [
         "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
]
```

Comment: Since Angular +6 the `.angular-cli.json` has baeen replaced by `.angular.json` file.

Comment: what if i want to import it in specifc compoent's .scss

Answer (score 5):

No need to add like this. in your `angular-cli.json` file add style tag with the script path

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
]
```

remove the script from your component

```
styleUrls: ['./myComponent.component.scss'],
```